# How can you wrap a graphql request in a pg-promise transaction

Tags: node.js, transactions, graphql, pg-promise

PG-Promise provides a nice safe transaction wrapper

```
db.tx(t => {
    // Here you can use t to run any queries
    // in a single transaction, on a single connection.
})
```

Apollo GraphQL Express provides an Express middleware that handles GraphQL requests. It depends on a set of predefined "resolvers" which resolve different parts of the request. These resolvers are called from the library, and their results put together to form a response.

I would like to be able to wrap a GraphQL request, which be fetching multiple pieces of data or performing multiple database operations (mutations), in a pg-promise transaction so that there is basic transactional integrity. There is no obvious-to-me way to do this.

The best idea I've come up with is to create my own middleware to run before GraphQL, which adds a new transaction task to the request object:

```
const bindTx = (req, res, next) => {
    db.tx(async (t) => {
        req = Object.assign(req, {getTransaction: () => t})
        await next()
    })
}
```

My thought here is that this middleware will make sure the next middleware runs inside the transaction. I put this in the Express chain before GraphQL:

```
app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), bindTx, graphql)
```

My `graphql` setup then takes the transaction added to the request by `bindTx` and passes it to the resolvers through the `context`:

```
const graphql = graphqlExpress((req) => {
  const t = req.getTransaction()

  return {
    schema: makeExecutableSchema({
      typeDefs,
      resolvers
    }),
    context: {t}
  }
}
```

Finally, a resolver might look like this:

```
getSomethingById(_, {somethingId}, context) {
  context.t.one(
    'select * from something where id = ${somethingId}',
    {somethingId}
  )
}
```

Since I understand that GraphQL runs resolvers in sequence, and they can return a promise which must be resolved before the next resolver runs, I thought this would work.

This seems to result in a race condition, where most times it generates an error `Unhandled rejection Error: Querying against a released or lost connection.` I believe this means that the transaction was already closed when the resolvers ran and tried to query against it.

I am not attached to this approach at all, in fact it seems overcomplicated, but I am looking for some way to make my GraphQL resolution run inside a transaction. Although I am currently using Express, Apollo, and PG-Promise, these are not requirements, if other libraries can solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: First: Resolvers' promises don't have to return before the next one runs. This is only the case for mutations' top level fields. Second: I don't think you can await the `next` function in express. In my experience writing a middleware that _wraps_ middleware downstream is rather difficult in express. *But* you can do this in [koa](https://github.com/koajs/koa), just also await the transaction. If you can easily change the http framework I highly recommend a framework that works with promises/await. I have no idea why people still use express in the post Node 6 era.

Comment: A transaction body expects an optional promise inside it, which means you can chain any functionality inside the transaction, while it is running. You can even do complex sequencing, like in [this example](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Data-Imports).

Comment: @Herku, thank you, that is a fantastic suggestion. I am not attached to Express in any way, it was just the default. Once I have time to get back to this, I'll try Koa.

I edited the question a little to make clear that the tools are optional.

Comment: @vitaly-t, I have been nothing but impressed with PG-Promise so far. The problem here, to my thinking, is more with the other tools, or with my lack of understanding.